# jQuery Add domain in links

Tags: jquery

I have a lot of download links provided for my users in my site and I would like to add specific reference link to those links. For example:

```
http://rapidgator.net/file/xxxx
```

Now I want to use jQuery to add my referent links in front of every link that they go out to external links. I searched and only found the jQuery for `attr`:

```
jQuery('a[href*="http://"]:not([href*="http://www.mysite.com"])').attr('rel', 'nofollow');
```

But in my case I want to add my domain in front of the links so that URL:

```
<a href="http://rapidgator.net/file/xxxx">http://rapidgator.net/file/xxxx</a>
```

Will become:

```
<a href="http://myspecificdomain.com?ref=http://rapidgator.net/file/xxx">http://rapidgator.net/file/xxxx</a>
```

Can this be done using jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually You are almost there, you already can get all the elements you want, all you have to do is loop them and replace the href attribute:

```
$('a[href*="http://"]:not([href*="http://myspecificdomain.com"])').each(function(index){
    $(this).attr('href',"http://myspecificdomain.com?ref="+$(this).attr('href'))
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/63pMH/1/

But still, this will not find anchors with links starting with "www", unless all your links don't have the www prefix

Comment: Thank you I mark this as very simple and not confused with real demo...thanks Sari Alalen

Comment: This is actually my answer posted 12 minutes later.

Answer (score 0):

This will find all links that start with `http://` and do not already include links to your site. You can edit that statement accordingly. It then loops through each of the links, captures the current `href`, then appends it to end of your `ref` text:

```
$('a[href*="http://"]:not([href*="http://www.mysite.com"])').each(function(){
    var current = $(this).attr("href");
    $(this).attr("href", "http://myspecificdomain.com?ref=" + current);
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/LpbMN/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)'s [attr](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) function.

We will read the links' `href` attribute and form a new string in your desired format of `http://myspecificdomain.com?ref=original_link` and update the `href`.

**Steps**

1. *Select the links you want to manipulate.* They can be all links, a single link identified by an `id`, or multiple links identified by `class`, or more advanced selectors ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)).
2. *Read the `href`, manipulate it, and update it.*

***Edit:*** Code and JSFiddle demo updated to manage links not beginning with 'http://' (as suggested by Sari Alalem). The following will scan all links, and manipulate all but the `http://myspecificdomain.com`

jQuery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a').each(function(index) {
            var originalUrl = $(this).attr('href');

            if (originalUrl != 'http://myspecificdomain.com') {
                var modifiedUrl = 'http://myspecificdomain.com?ref=' + $(this).attr('href');
                $(this).attr('href', modifiedUrl)
            }

            alert($(this).attr('href')); // debug code, remove
        });
    });
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gopal1035/cD4kG/3/)